# Encrypt in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, encryption, cryptography

I want to encrypt some users confidential data using AES algrotitm in System.Security.Cryptography and store it in Database.

So my question is how I should store keys for decode private data. 
And how to get Key and IV vector.

Maybe It should have opportunity to share this data, i mean using private/public keys.

Answer (score -1):

You have two option : 
 1. If you key and IV is static for all users you can store it in Web.config , so you can
    access it from you application and nobody else can access .
 2. If your key and IV is different for each user , you can save a specific
        pattern in your web config and use it . The pattern is something like this

```
UserID+NationalCode+BirthDate
```

then in your your encryption method parse this pattern , append the items , convert to byte array and use each part of string as key and IV .

Comment: I think that storing confidential data like this is not secure, cause if somebody can get access to server there will be easy to decrypt data. I Think that maybe better get key in code using some users data, because disassembly algorithm code harder, than to read config file.